# How to replace label line with dot in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to change label line with dot. The part of i want to change i took it in a circle as you see in below picture.

[image]

How can I do it in highchart.js ?

Comment: But you want just one dot there? Or line should be dotted?

Comment: just lines with dotes like this picture https://gyazo.com/dfaf3525bdd96afb3af76a95f62a90aa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is not supported, but it is very easy to achieve. Simply wrap `getMarkPath` method and return path you want to use, for example, cirlce:

```
(function(H){
  H.wrap(H.Tick.prototype, 'getMarkPath', function(p, x, y, tickLength, tickWidth, horiz, renderer) {
    return renderer.symbols.circle(x - tickLength / 2, y - tickLength / 2, tickLength, tickLength);
  });  
})(Highcharts)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9pj3kxr6/2/